# Can I teach my iPhone to autocapitalize?

Tags: customization, autocorrect

My name is not an English word or common enough name to be in whatever list of proper nouns it has, and I always have to capitalize it manually. It doesn't even show up as an autocorrect option. Is there a way around this? It seems like a phone that can do so many things should at least be able to learn my name. iPhone 4 with iOS up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I would define your name as a keyboard shortcut, so if your name were `nisht`, I would set the phrase to be `Nisht` and the shortcut to be `nisht`.

To add a keyboard shortcut: Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have yourself in the contacts application and have that contact selected as yourself? I believe that will add your name to the autocorrect list.